# What is the right syntax for grep to retrieve google ngram entries?

Tags: grep

The google ngram format is similar to this:

```
apollo_.        2008    6   5
apollonia_NOUN  1760    1   1
apollo.5        1760    1   1
apollo          2008    6   5
```

If I just want to pull out the line containing the word 'apollo' without a suffix what would the correct grep command be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this dataset you could do:

```
$ grep '^apollo\s' file
apollo          2008    6   5
```

That is `grep` for lines starting with `apollo` followed by a whitespace character. Options related to this kind of matching with `grep` are:

> -w, --word-regexp
>
> Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that  form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.
>                 Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
>
> x, --line-regexp
>
> Select only those matches that exactly match the whole line.  (-x is specified by POSIX.)

You also have the regular expression option of using `\b` to match the word boundary however this and the `grep` option `-w` fails for this particular data on the line `apollo.5` due to the punctuation `.` after `apollo`.

Comment: what if apollo is present at the end of the line?

Comment: @Vijay then you would use the appropriate solution for that dataset. The OP has made very clear his problem, one regex to rule them all is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
perl -lne 'print if(/\bapollo(\s+|$)/)' your_file
```

Comment: Neither of those prevent the formats with the . being found. For example it strips out apollonia_NOUN but not apollo.5

Comment: @chris...Updated...please check now.